# Tomcat 5.5 and Tomcat 6 side by side on same server

Tags: linux, tomcat6, sles, tomcat5.5

On Suse Linux server I have Tomcat 5.5. installed (port 8080)

Can I also install Tomcat 6 on the same server (side by side) but on different port (for example 8081).

Are there any pitfalls I should be aware of?

Since this is production server, what are your advices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Manually install it in /opt, change server.xml to your needs (port). Do not forget to add a start/stop script in case a reboot is needed.

Be sure you have enough memory for both. Depending on the application, you will need several gigs of RAM.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Do you have any suggestions for multiple java versions? (currenty java 1.5 is installed, I would like to have java 6 on the new tomcat instance). Maybe setting JAVA_HOME would help, but where?

Comment: Yes, I use to have all my java versions extracted into /opt and added in classpath.sh on each tomcat.